# How to block cells when file opens?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some formulas set via vba to change the value in columns H, J, K, L and N. Those changes are based on G column value and a Submit button, this works fine.

When I do the process to lock them to avoid the user from editing, that says to unlock the whole sheet then lock the ones I need, after this I modify the G column and get:

> "Autofit Method of Range Class Failed".

I use it on H column.

This get highlighted:

```
Sheet1.Range("H11:H50").Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

Comment: Please include all the code in this subroutine, not just the line it fails on. It sounds like you are locking the H column and then trying to make a change to it.

Comment: You will most likely need to unlock the sheet and then relock it in order to make the change using VBA.

Comment: Try to use the `Autofit` method first and _then_ lock the H column. Moreover, the Title of your Q doesn't reflect on your actual question.

Comment: What I am trying to do is block those columns so the user do not input anything. But the value from those columns change via different formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change protected cells using VBA while the protection is on. You can work around this various ways, however, the most simple solution is something like the following:

```
Sub Example()

Sheet1.Unprotect "YOURPASSWORD" 'if no password was used, you don't need to include it
Sheet1.Range("H11:H50").Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
Sheet1.Protect "YOURPASSWORD"

End Sub
```

**Alternative solution:**

By using this in the on open procedure of your workbook. VBA can make changes on locked cells, but users can not.

One Caveat: if an error occurs in the code, this will reset and you need to close and reopen the worksheet in order for this to function again

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. So I have to do that for every column I want to block that gets changed from different formulas results?

Comment: I updated my answer... this might make it easier to implement so you don't need to do it for each sheet.